# sudo prompts for password over ssh

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have sudo set up for a user (myuser) as follows on "hostname" (sudoers content):

```
Cmnd_Alias SCRIPT=/path/script*
myuser ALL=(suser) NOPASSWD: SCRIPT
```

this works fine, so I can run the following, logged in locally as myuser on hostname, without need for password:

```
sudo -u suser /path/script
```

however, when I use ssh (with keys set up, so no password required) to login and run, as follows:

```
ssh hostname sudo -u suser /path/script
```

I get prompted for a password, and when the password is entered I get:

```
Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/path/script' as suser on hostname
```

.

**UPDATE**
The problem is solved by removing the "*" from the end of the command in sudoers.
The * was added to allow parameters to be passed to script, but actually doesn't appear to be necessary.
Still don't understand why the * allows the sudo to work locally, but not over ssh.
So question still stands

Comment: Are you logging into an SSH server that requires password authentication?

Comment: no, I have keys set up

Comment: In your sudoers file, did you use the ALL keyword? You may want to try an ALL=ALL config just to identify the root cause. user ALL=(ALL) ALL NO PASSWD: ALL If that config works, and it should, then the remaining task is just paring back the permissions to the appropriate level.

Comment: when you get asked for a password, if you supply it does the command work ok ?

Comment: @Iain - no, it says my user is not allowed to execute the script as user on hostname

Comment: Ok, you should have told us that too. As you're not the sysadmin then there really isn't much you can do except report it to your sysadmin. For future reference this site it for sysadmins and people who have suitable privilege to carry out system operations which (in this case) you don't.

Comment: OK, well sorry to have wasted a bit of time - my sysadmin still hasn't responded, so was hoping to help things along. Thanks - will post back problem/solution when get it

Comment: well, I got the sudoers content, and added it to OP. It specifies ALL=(user) - so shouldn't that be OK?  My sysadmin does not currently know the answer, so consider me his proxy :)

Comment: @JoeWatkins, if you have more than one rule in the sudoers that applies, the last rule is the effective rule. That is something to look at, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working

Comment: @Somantra I'm waiting to get the full sudoers file at the moment, but one thing that looks a bit odd is that for the sudo user (for which I have password), a sudo -l shows the same script as my user:
(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/script*
so maybe there is a conflict? although why only over ssh? need to get full file so see what host is defined for that user

Comment: @JoeWatkins, right. You need to confirm that there is not another rule later in the sudoers file that is overriding the rule you posted. And it can be a group rule too, not a user rule that is conflicting.

Comment: @Somantra no joy. There was a prior rule for suser for the same script, which was confusing, but removing that didn't help. The rule shown is the last one in the sudoers file

Comment: OP updated - now have a solution - to remove the * after command. Do not understand why this fixes though...

Comment: @JoeWatkins, the syntax is certainly a bit arcane, but * is essentially the regex character to match 0 or more of the preceding character. I only see examples of /path/* not /path/script*. /path/* should work for your purposes, maybe /path/script_dir/* would be better.

Comment: @Somantra OK, I didn't realise it was regex - in that case the usage makes no sense at all. The intention was to allow any characters after the script name (i.e. using it as a shell filename glob type match to allow parameters), but actually that is not required anyway. Question remains - why did this cause it to fail over ssh but not locally?

Comment: @JoeWatkins, in that case, I think the syntax would be like /path/script -[abcdefg]*, but you're right, you obviously don't need the asterisk in this case.

Comment: What OS/Version is this? I found some Ubuntu bug reports a while back that were very similar: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/449247

Comment: @somantra - jeez this gets more complicated all the time! I've just read man for sudoers (yes, maybe I should have done this at the start), and it looks that * is a regex in the rules, but is shell style in cmnd_list alias. In fact, in this case the command is in an alias, and I simplified in the original post by including in rule. I'll amend that, although the original question still remains - why this affects ssh

Comment: @somantra i'm ssh'ing from a RHEL 4.7 box to an Oracle EL 5.4 server (where sudoers is)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a host in the sudoers, so it only works locally as you have it setup now.

So if you set the host parameter to ALL, it will work on any host.

From *man sudoers*:

> > The reserved word ALL is a built-in alias that always causes a match to succeed.  It can be used wherever one might otherwise use a
> >            Cmnd_Alias, User_Alias, Runas_Alias, or Host_Alias.

...

> > By default, if the NOPASSWD tag is applied to any of the entries for a user on the current host, he or she will be able to run sudo -l
> >            without a password.  Additionally, a user may only run sudo -v without a password if the NOPASSWD tag is present for all a user's
> >            entries that pertain to the current host.  This behavior may be overridden via the verifypw and listpw options.

The additional fact that the following works at the terminal seems to bear out that the host is the reason you get prompted.

> > $ ssh hostname
> >
> > $ sudo -u user /path/script

Comment: OK, I'll have a word with sysadmin, and try to change. Thanks

Comment: The output of `sudo -l` which the OP posts doesn't show the hostname portion of the spec from the sudoers file.

Comment: I only need to run this on one host - so can that host get specified in the sudoers file? (rather than ALL)

Comment: @Lain, it is true that that the sudo-l shows info for the current host only, still seems to be behaving that way though.

Comment: @JoeWatkins, yes, just specify the desired hostname in the sudoers config as Lain has documented in his answer.

Comment: If you try to specify an sudoers entry without a hostname or Host_Alias then visudo will not save the file. Like me you have been misdirected by the OP not saying that the apparent sudoers line above was generated by `sudo -l`.

Comment: @Lain, good catch, just tried that in Darwin visudo. My new guess is it is setup as localhost.

Comment: I already tried that on a CentOS 6 system - it doesn't work when logged in or remotely.

Comment: @Lain, alas the reason why ALL is so seductive. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are showing for the sudoers file is incorrect and visudo won't let you create a file with that syntax. It should be something like

```
testuser hostname=(user) NOPASSWD: /path/script*
```

Using this syntax I can ssh to hostname and execute a script without eing asked for a password.

**EDIT**

From reading the comments it seems that there is an misconfiguration in your sudoers file. This would appear to be something to to with the Host_Alias or hostname specification part of the line.

I've set up a testuser on a CentOS 6 system and tried various configurations and can't find one that works when I'm logged in locally but denies me access when trying via ssh.

Comment: I don't have access to the sudoers file. I'm showing the output of sudo -l. The sudo works fine with no password prompt when run locally.

Comment: Ah, right - I wish you'd said that in your question.

Comment: amended question so hopefully all the relevant facts are now in it